# Css styling is not getting updated in IE Mode

Tags: javascript, css

I'm updating the css in my javascript file but I noticed it isn't applying in IE Mode. It works fine in all other browsers.

Does anyone know why IE Mode is a problem and how to fix it?

Here is the code I'm using

```js
var extraEl = document.querySelector("#suiteBarRight");
extraEl.style = "padding:10px;";
    
var extraEl2 = document.querySelector("#suiteBarLeft");
extraEl2.style = "display:none";
    
var extraEl3 = document.querySelector("#welcomeMenuBox");
extraEl3.style = "display:none";
    
var extraEl4 = document.querySelector("#suiteBarButtons");
extraEl4.style = "display:none";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the style property of an element, you need to access the style object's individual properties rather than assigning a string. For example:

```
extraEl.style.padding = "10px";
```